# How to quickly generate persistence.xml from jpa/hibernate classes

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence.xml

It is sometimes tedious to add class names manually to the persistence.xml file for hibernate configuration. 
Is there a way to quickly generate the `<class>com.something.Entity1</class>`  part of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple way, using the code from [dzone.](http://dzone.com/snippets/get-all-classes-within-package) And just print them out and copy from the console. 
Here it is for anyone interested.

```
Class[] classex = getClasses(Entity1.class.getPackage().getName());
    for (Class c : classex) {
        if (c.getName().contains("$")) continue;
        if (!c.isAnnotationPresent(javax.persistence.Entity.class)) continue;
        System.out.println("<class>" + c.getName() + "</class>");
    }
```